# Can I become a professor in a subject I did badly in?

Tags: career-path, professorship

I am a third year math undergraduate student. I am in Europe (Serbia) but would like to do a postgraduate degree in the USA. My freshman year went poorly, but after that I started to do a lot better. But, in my first year I took a real analysis class and scored a C. In the meantime, I revisited all my first year classes, did a lot of math and greatly improved.

Now, real analysis is one of my favourite math areas and I would like to teach it one day at university. But, my question is, are my chances very low (or nonexistent) because I screwed up a class in which I want to become a professor? I know generally getting a job is academia is pretty hard but am I in a really bad spot compared to others, considering what I want to do in future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the US and I suppose other places, it is possible to overcome early difficulties, even failures, and still succeed. But it requires evidence of change and advancement, which you may already be showing.

For US doctoral applications you want good letters of recommendation from people who can honestly predict your success. With that and a better record in the recent years you have a good chance. The competition is difficult, of course, but an early low grade isn't disqualifying.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you don't become a professor of real analysis; you become a professor of mathematics and then you may or may not teach real analysis.  In any department I've ever been affiliated with, there are no additional qualifications a faculty member needs to show in order to teach a certain course.  If others have more expertise and/or have taught the course before, they may get priority; otherwise *someone* needs to teach the course, and they trust you to know what you're getting into.

I didn't remember this until I started answering this question, but: actually the worst grade I ever got in a university level math course was a graduate course in real analysis that I took as an undergraduate.  They let me take the next analysis course in the graduate sequence anyway.  I went on to do a PhD in algebraic number theory, but over the years my interest in analytic topics has increased (also the interest of algebraic number theorists in general in analytic topics has increased), and this semester I am teaching undergraduate real analysis for the second time. At this rate it is reasonably likely that one day I will teach a version of the graduate real analysis course that I struggled with in my student years.

I also remember reading many years ago an abstract algebra text (I believe it was the one by Joseph Gallian) that included brief biographies of certain twentieth century algebraists.  It mentioned [Michael Aschbacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Aschbacher).  Quoting (now *not* from memory):

> "In his senior year, Aschbacher
> took abstract algebra but showed little interest in the course. Accordingly, he received a
> grade of C."

He grew up to be one of the greatest group theorists who ever lived and probably the person who contributed the most to the classification of finite simple groups.  People get better at things as they learn more.  Just because you don't understand a deep mathematical concept at the age of (say) 19 doesn't mean that you never will.

If you are asking about your prospects for graduate admission, then I have clear advice for you: keep taking mathematics courses and try to do better in your more advanced and more recent coursework.  If you do better in a higher level real analysis course than you did in a lower level real analysis course, then people are going to think that you learned real analysis.

Comment: The sentence "First of all, you don't become a professor of real analysis; you become a professor of mathematics" is correct in the context of, say, US, UK and Canada. Things are a bit different in Eastern Europe (and even in Germany). This remark does not affect the main point you are making.

Comment: This happens routinely. I'm teaching the math course I received the lowest grade of my student career, albeit 13 years ago, this semester.

Comment: While your answer is good and correct, let me add that "famous person X received a bad grade" in biographies often means "X did badly with respect to extremly high standards" (eg in a very competitive uni) or "X had original thoughts, but the teacher only cared about rote learning" and is not comparable to the bad grade of an avarage person;) it makes a good biographic story, I think. (I haven't researched Thompson 's biography, could be that he really did show little interest in comparision to the avarage math student, not "avarage extraordinary uni math student"

Comment: @user111388: The problem with quoting from memory is that one's memory is often not completely accurate.  I went back to look up the quote, and it was said about Aschbacher, not Thompson -- i.e., about a different world leader in finite group theory.  Your point about what wondering what a C grade at a certain school at a certain time -- in this case, at Caltech in the 1960's -- really means is still a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Summary: Definetely, you can.

I come from a relatively progressive country and studied in the 2010's (and went before to high school). Despite of that, I had some teachers and professors who explicitly stated that they do not only grade your subject results, but also 'play God' ('only God can earn an A in my course', 'women will not pass my course' (and even worse sexist statements!), 'you study to become a teacher, so you must be stupid and cannot get an A even if you are perfect', "I don't like your face, you lose a point" (and much more).

While such teachers and professors become, luckily, more and more rare, there are likely many with implicit biases. And everybody I know knows some of such teachers.

And then there is even more the 'problem' that one might have had a bad day on exam day, one class was unreasonably difficult etc.

My point is: People are aware that a single grade does not tell you much about a person's capabilities in a subject. When I look at grades, I look at the collection of all grades - this gives more information about whether you are a good student or not. And real analysis is not so special - I'd say that any student who is good enough to do research in math can also do research in real analysis, if they are interested in it.

And when it really comes to you becoming a professor, people look at your research in real analysis. Your grade is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

Where is JeffE when you need him?

Jeff Erickson was an instructor of mine at the University of Illinois. He mentioned his GPA was around 2.5 and (Bs and Cs) and his computer-science focused GPA was similar. (It is part of his homepage - https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/).

Needless to say, it may be difficult if there are automated or near-automated GPA thresholds, but all things equal, I would expect a student with a bad class grade (especially a single grade) but good research-type work (perhaps published but more likely evidenced by letters of recommendation) to perform better than a student with a high grade and no research experience. This is doubly so if the class was early in the progression, and the student did well on classes that built on that material. Math may be different (my research area is human-computer interaction) but I would expect that to still hold true.

Furthermore, many (all?) US-based PhD programs have a personal statement as part of an application. Among other things, you can detail more about what you learned and how you improved as a mathematician through that first year and how you're better today. I would expect that to assuage worries about that particularly low grade if they do come up.